# Amplifying millivolt signal to volts from shunt resistor for current detection: Single supply or dual supply op amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, shunt

What are the pros and cons of configuring an op amp to be a single supply op amp vs a dual supply for amplifying very small signals? I am using three of the OPA177GP op amps to build a 3-op amp instrumentation amplifier since it has a low offset voltage and low drift.

In general what should I be cautious about when designing my own 3-opamp instrumentation amplifier?

Comment: If you are amplifying the output of a current shunt, it might be simpler to use a chip designed for that purpose, such as the LTC6102.

Comment: Okay thanks, but is there a through-hole version of that chip?

Comment: A quick search for "Current Sense Amplifier" from various vendors suggests they are all surface-mount. If you can only use DIL parts, you'll find the range is very limited, and shrinking. You can use a surface mount part instead by soldering it onto a surface-mount-to-DIL adaptor board, maybe with a decoupling capacitor soldered directly across the supply pins. You just have to choose a part with reasonably-pitched easy-to-solder leads (e.g. 1.27 mm pitch SOIC) and get an adaptor board to match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an OP177 amplifier. Its input and output range stop a volt or two short of each rail, so it necessary to use power supply rails well above and below all of your input and output voltages. It's not clear what potential your shunt is sitting at, providing its millivolt signal, but if it's around ground potential, then you need to supply your amplifier with rails that are well above and below ground, which is most easily done with a dual supply.

Amplifiers are available whose input range exceeds the rails, however no amplifier's output range can exceed the rails. If your measured current never went to zero, this would allow you to use a suitable rail-to-rail amplifier with a single supply.

You can roll your own instrumentation amplifier, but you need to pay attention to resistor matching to get good CMRR. It's often better to buy a single IC in-amp, made with internal monolithic matched resistors, and a specification on the CMRR.

Comment: Ohh okay I see! That makes sense why my output from the opamp was around a constant 0.674V even when the current changed through the shunt. I didn't realize that my amplified voltage from the input was still close to the ground rail value. So I guess I either need to change my opamp to a single supply rail to rail or use a dual supply. Do you know what other precision amplifiers are available that are rail to rail? Do you also know a technique to create a dual supply rail with a positive and negative voltage? Sorry I am quite new to electronics.